# Getting "Undefined variable: categories" error in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm learning laravel and writing a simple project while learning it, but there is a problem that I couldn't solve.
I have a form which is for creating an article like this :

```
<form action="{{route('admin.article.store')}}" method="POST">
@csrf
        
        //some divs

        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title">Category</label>
        <div id="output"></div>
        <select class="chosen-select" name="categories[]" multiple style="width:400px">
          @foreach ($categories as $cat_name => $cat_id)
          <option value="{{$cat_id}}">{{$cat_name}}</option>
          @endforeach
        </select>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="title"></label>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-inverse-success btn-fw">Create</button>
            <a href="{{route('admin.article.index')}}" class="btn btn-inverse-warning btn-fw">back</a>
        </div>

</form>
```

And in my controller, I'm storing this requests like this :

```
$article = $article->create($request->all());
$article->categories()->attach($request->$categories);
```

but after testing, it says:

**ErrorException**

Undefined variable: categories

what can I do?

Comment: You have not defined `$categories`,  you are using on your foreach loop. Post your controller code, and  probably `index` function.

Comment: no, the view is ok, the foreach loops correctly and displays the categories, but the problem is when I try to save (store) the form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a typo mistake.
You are using `$request->$categories`, should be `$request->categories`. Remove the extra dollar (`$`) sign.

```
$article->categories()->attach($request->categories);
```

Comment: Oh thank you, I've been searching for typo but not this type, sorry